# Read data from MongoDB and apply Filter on Multilevel JSON in Scala Spark Connector

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I am using the MongoDb Scala connector for Spark. In the documentation
https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/aggregation/

it is mentioned that how to apply filter on the given JSON document. What I am not able to figure out that if we have a multilevel json and we want to apply filter on it how will we access that key/value in the json Document.

**Json Document:**

```
{ "_id" : 1, "test" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 2, "test" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 3, "test" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 4, "test" : 4 }
{ "_id" : 5, "test" : 5 }
{ "_id" : 6, "test" : 6 }
```

**Filter Document:**

```
val rdd = MongoSpark.load(sc)

val filteredRdd = rdd.filter(doc => doc.getInteger("test") > 5)
println(filteredRdd.count)
println(filteredRdd.first.toJson)
```

**Multilevel Json Document**

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "test": 1,
    "additionalProperties": {
        "value": "35",
        "phone": "566623232"
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I want to filter on the basis of "value" attribute but I don't know how to access it. I tried to do following but it is not working.

```
val filteredRdd = rdd.filter(doc => doc.getInteger("value") > 5)

val filteredRdd = rdd.filter(doc => doc.getInteger("additionalProperties.value") > 5)
```

Can anybody guide me that how can I access the "value" attribute? What would be the right syntax.

**Some Other Options that I have tried:**

According to the official documentation of Scala Connector for Spark of MongoDB. I tried filtering the document with the **Aggregation Pipeline.** So Following line of code works fine:

```
val filterWithPipeline = customRdd.withPipeline(Seq(Document.parse("{ $match: { id: { $eq : '134' } } }")))
```

But IF I want to access the "value" item by using the same syntax. It doesn't work.

```
 val filterWithPipeline = customRdd.withPipeline(Seq(Document.parse("{ $match: { value: { $eq : '134' } } }")))
```

So How can I use the same approach to query the multi level JSON?

Comment: Do you have requirement to use only RDD or dataframe is fine too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are couple of ways you can read from mongoDB and filter it 
Creating SparkSession

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("Test")
  .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/db.collectionName")
  .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/db.CollectionName")
  .getOrCreate

import spark.implicits._
import com.mongodb.spark.sql._
```

Read as `MongoRDD[Document]` and filter it

```
MongoSpark.load(spark.sparkContext).filter(doc => {
  val value = doc.get("additionalProperties").asInstanceOf[Document].get("value")
  value.toString.toInt > 5
})
```

Read as `Dataframe` with spark.read.mongo()

```
val filterDF = spark.read.mongo().filter($"additionalProperties.value".lt(5))
```

Output:

```
+---+--------------------+----+
|_id|additionalProperties|test|
+---+--------------------+----+
|2.0|[5, 566623232]      |2.0 |
+---+--------------------+----+
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

What if you use the dafaframe?

```
val df = spark.read.json("path")
```

Here is my example,

```
+---+--------------------+----+
|_id|additionalProperties|test|
+---+--------------------+----+
|1  |[566623232, 35]     |1   |
|2  |[566623232, 35]     |2   |
|3  |[566623232, 1]      |3   |
+---+--------------------+----+
```

and the schema is

```
root
 |-- _id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- additionalProperties: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- phone: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test: long (nullable = true)
```

Then,

```
df.filter(col("additionalProperties").getItem("value").cast("int") > 5)
```

will give the result such as:

```
+---+--------------------+----+
|_id|additionalProperties|test|
+---+--------------------+----+
|1  |[566623232, 35]     |1   |
|2  |[566623232, 35]     |2   |
+---+--------------------+----+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I want to return the selected documents as JSON. How can I do that from data frame.

Comment: And what imports i need to do in my scala code? Can you highlight that as well please.

Comment: `df.write.mode('write').json(yourtargetpath)` you can choose the mode for write or append for existing file.

Comment: maybe `import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset` `import org.apache.spark.sql.Row`

Comment: Hi, I am not able to resolve the error on column line . Following are my imports:
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, Dataset, Row,Column}
import com.mongodb.spark.config._
import com.mongodb.spark._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import org.bson.Document

Comment: Can you guide me which import I am missing.

Comment: For my code, I have only included those two imports as I mentioned and so if you struggle some error that is not related to the topic I guess. I need more details about what error comes and what stage in your code.

Comment: when I write this line of code : df.filter(col("additionalProperties").getItem("value").cast("int") > 5). The Intellij IDE doesn't recognize the col command. And give a syntax error.

Comment: Is that happen even after you import the Column? `import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, Dataset, Row, Column}` I put a space before Column imports and the Column class is the required one for `col`.

Comment: The error is there before and after importing the column.

Comment: the import doesn't seems to have any effect on the error which is that IDE is not recognizing it as a valid syntax. I am using Apache Spark connector version 2.4.0

Comment: might be a problem of mongodb connector and mine is a pure scala spark.

Comment: You might be right , but I have to use the mongodb connector.

Comment: Yeap, try to use the [sql queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/datasets-and-sql/). `characters.createOrReplaceTempView("table")` and `sparkSession.sql("select * from table where cast(additionalProperties.value as int) > 5)"`.